# ¿Cómo sumar la diferencia de cuatro campos tipo time con php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo en mi tabla cuatro campos tipo time: hora_inicio, hora_salida_almuerzo, hora_llegada_almuerzo, hora_salida, he intentado restar las horas, para calcular el numero de cada jornada, es decir si en la mañana trabajo de 8-12, la resta da cuatro, y en la tarde de 1-5pm tambien da cuatro, ahora eso no lo sé sumar en sentencias mysql, aqui está mi codigo:

```
<?
include('conex.php');
$conexion=conectarse();

$resta1="TIMEDIFF(hora_salida_almuerzo,hora_inicio)";
$resta2="TIMEDIFF(hora_salida,hora_llegada_almuerzo)";

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT id_horario,$resta1,$resta2  
from horario",$conexion);


$registro=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);

echo $registro[1];
echo "<br>";
echo $registro[2];

?>
```

el funciona pero no sé como sumar ambos resultados y que de formato h:i:s para luego insertarlos en la tabla horarios.

Answer (score 1):

ok primero que nada deja de usar mysql esa libreria esta depreciada, por otro lado, deberias de utilizar **SEC_TO_TIME** y **TIME_TO_SEC** en la misma consulta para retornar la suma de ambas en formato hora, por ejemplo:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas");
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}

$a = $db->query("SELECT id,
                        TIMEDIFF(s_almuerzo, entrada) as manana, 
                        TIMEDIFF(salida,e_almuerzo) as tarde,
                        SEC_TO_TIME(
                                TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(s_almuerzo, entrada) ) + 
                                TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(salida,e_almuerzo) )
                        ) as total FROM horarios");
$row = $a->fetch_object();
var_dump($row);
```

En esta parte del codigo se calculan las diferencias entre un rango de horas:

```
TIMEDIFF(s_almuerzo, entrada) as primera, 
TIMEDIFF(salida,e_almuerzo) as segunda,
```

Luego entra **SEC_TO_TIME** a convertir en hora el resultado final de la suma de los segundos de dichas diferencias:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(
```

dentro de SEC_TO_TIME colocamos nuevamente el calculo de diferencia entre los campos, pero encerrandolos con la instrucción **TIME_TO_SEC** la cual los convierte en segundos para que el calculo de SEC_TO_TIME lo transforme en horas de manera correcta, tomando en cuenta horas, minutos y segundos de dicha hora.

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(s_almuerzo, entrada) ) + 
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(salida,e_almuerzo) )
```

al final esto nos retorna un objeto con la información del primer bloque de calculo, del segundo bloque de calculo y del total de horas de ese periodo:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["manana"]=> string(8) "03:00:00" ["tarde"]=> string(8) "05:00:00" ["total"]=> string(8) "08:00:00" }
```

Con **TIME_TO_SEC** pasamos a segundos las diferencias calculadas mientras que con **SEC_TO_TIME** la pasamos a horas, y pues con los alias manejamos mejor las salidas de codigo de nuestra consulta.

Comment: Voy a probarlo gracias de antemano, pero la verdad no entendi nada no he programado nunca con esas instrucciones para mi nuevas, se me habia ocurrido era pasar lo que me daba en echo $registro[1] y echo $registro[2]; a tiempo en segundos, sumar esos tiempos y el resultado transformarlo a formato h:m:s, nuevamente

Comment: exactamente eso hace el código que te coloque, pero directamente en la instrucción sql, lo que te ahorra lineas de código y te permite enfocarte en otros elementos de tu script

Answer (score 0):

Para restar horas suponiendo que ya tienes en varibles las horas que necesitas restar.

Agregue tambie el **GMT** para que sea mas exacta la hora

```
<?php
$hora1 = strtotime($hora_salida_almuerzo ."GMT", 0);
$hora2 = strtotime($hora_inicio."GMT", 0);

$diferencia = $hora2 + $hora1 ;

$horas = $diferencia / 3600;
$minutos = ($diferencia % 3600) / 60;

echo sprintf("%d:%d", $horas, $minutos);

?>
```

Comment: suponiendo esto: $hora_salida_almuerzo="12:00:00";
$hora_inicio="08:00:00"; aplicando el codigo que compartiste da -28:00

Comment: lo siento no me fije que puse al revez la horas ya la modifique, puede ser tambien por GMT porque puede estar dando otra hora eso depende de donde vivas

Comment: <?

$hora_salida_almuerzo="12:00:00";
$hora_inicio="08:00:00";

$hora1 = strtotime($hora_salida_almuerzo ."GMT", 0);
$hora2 = strtotime($hora_inicio."GMT", 0);

$diferencia = $hora2 + $hora1 ;

$horas = $diferencia / 3600;
$minutos = ($diferencia % 3600) / 60;

echo sprintf("%d:%d", $horas, $minutos);

?> eso da igual

Comment: quitale gmt prueba

Comment: strtotime() es para fechas no para datos time